# Best way to access external jar on local disk

Tags: java, hadoop, user-defined-functions, hive, hdfs

I am new to java so might be this is naive question, I have one external jar file which I want to move to Hadoop File system programatically, I have API to do so but just I need to give the path of the jar file. I don't want to go with hard coded path (both absolute and relative) maybe if I can include it along with my project or maybe something better so that same code works across different machines, its possible that same jar file might not present at the same location on different machines, if I will give hardcoded path then I need to explicitly copy the file to the same location.

---

I have written UDF (jar file) for Hive which is available on my disk, now to access UDF in Hive one need to add jar to HIVE classpath, so I thought to copy JAR file to HDFS from my local system and then Add jar to HIVE classpath from HDFS path.

Comment: One way is to get a `File` for the Jar then convert it to `URL` then use [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to load it.  That being said, the entire approach sounds wrong.  Why is the resource not simply built/loaded into Hadoop by the usual methods?

Comment: Cool.  Added it as a tag.  BTW - I also edited the crux of your 1st comment back into the question.  You can delete the comment now.

Answer (score 1):

You can put two jar files in the same directory and path would look like this

```
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "name.jar";
```

Where **System.getProperty("user.dir")**  will return user's current working directory (from where the first jar file was run), and **File.separator** is the system-dependent default name-separator character.

Comment: This won't work for me,here is my case,I have Java Class Library 'ABC' which will copy external jar file programatically.One will have Java application (main code) 'XYZ' which will reference 'ABC' jar to call 'ABC' functionalities, with the approach you suggested one need to put jar file alomg with 'XYZ' which is not feasiable for me

Comment: One approach I found was that I can do something similar to this File currentJarFilePath = new File <ClassName>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
String currentDirectory = currentJarFilePath.getParent();                   after that one can work with relative path to get desired extrenal jar file but I am looking if there is any better way to do this. Sorry for the confusion probably I should be more specific

Answer (score 0):

For using a UDF on Hive, you will have to add your UDF containing jar to the distributed cache so that it becomes available to all nodes in your Hive cluster.
You can do this with a syntax like the following:

```
add jar /path_to_jar/my_jar.jar
```

'/path_to_jar/' is path to the jar on your local machine from which you are running this command. The jar, if needed, can accessed from your MapReduce or Hive code by just its name after it has been added to the distributed cache.